# Caliburn.Micro & Windows Phone 8.1: How to pass parameters to the navigation GoBack() method?

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro

I have a WP 8.1 (native) app and I'm using Caliburn. Micro.
In the MainPageViewModel I navigate to the another page, where I want to set some value to the MyObject (property on the MainPageViewModel) and push it back to the MainPageViewModel.

So I navigate to the new page with passing myObject (it's working ok):

```
navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<AnotherPageViewModel>(myObject)
```

In the AnotherPageViewModel I set some values to the myObject and I return back to the MainPageViewModel:

```
navigationService.GoBack();
```

But how can I pass the changed myObject back to the MainPageViewModel? When I get back, the new instance of myObject in the MainPageViewModel is created.

EDIT:
I'd expect that the "changed" myObject will hold the changed values back in the MainPageViewModel after calling GoBack() method, but obviously a new instance is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things come to mind.

If you MainPageView does not set `NavigationCacheMode` to `Required` then a new instance of MainPageView and MainPageViewModel is created when navigating back. In this case, I would suggest you save the value after selection in AnotherPageViewModel somewhere (settings, etc.) and then load in when MainPageViewModel activates

If you MainPageView sets `NavigationCacheMode` to `Required`, then MainPageViewModel is not recreated when navigating back. In this case, I would suggest you use messaging (`IEventAggregator`). You can send a message to MainPageViewModel informating that the object changed and you may include the whole new object in the message.

Comment: I didn't know NavigationCacheMode = Required. It helped, thanks!